# TableView change of of behaviour

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I had a perfectly working app with multiple table views defined in a single Storyboard that has operated without issue for 18 months.

I recently changed to Xcode 5.0 and created a duplicate Storyboard, one configured for 4" screen and one for 3.5 with appropriate Delegate code to call the appropriate SB.

Although each TableView is essentially identical, some get called successfully and others crash with:-

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "m8N-d4-mjD-view-Yms-ZT-B8U" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

What's also unexpected, is some table views work on a connected device, but not in the Simulator and vice versa.

I have researched and tried many different things, but cannot fathom the apparent variable behaviour - any help gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

During the upgrade to Xcode5.0 my storyboards were damaged.
Check the following:
- Are the actual locations of the items in the Views correct (I had a lot of negative X and Y locations)?
- Are the links between the code and the items correct?

You said that you have copied the storyboard, a third solution is checking that the items are linked to the correct code version and not also to the previous version.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused - how would you check that the items are linked to the correct code version, you've thrown me a bit. Thanks Vincent.

Comment: Check the links defined in the Connection Inspection for each element. When you copy items, the link to the original IBOutlets in the .h file remain.

Comment: So for a button this may lead to the execution of 2x -(IBAction)functions. Which is (most of the time) not what you want. This may also lead to exception you describe above, since it is possible that 'old copies' refer to removed blocks in another part of your code.

Comment: I've checked all this out and it hasn't made any difference, I still get some table views working as normal and others crashing with the error. I'm beginning to think it's a memory issue as after rebuilding table views that were previously working are now not and vice versa.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If you're not using ARC, then you should autorelease your alloced objects. Please post your code, so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Yes I am using ARC. It's hard to know what code to share. A lot of the code is in the 2 storyboards. Another odd thing is that although the second storyboard was cloned off the first, some table views work in one but not the other.
When I clean, re-build and re-test, I get different table views working, it's all highly strange compared to the stability I had before.

Comment: Yet another oddity is some views work in the simulator but not on my iPhone and vice versa !!

Comment: Differences between simulator and phone occur more as you would expected. Please post your full project to Github, so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Please check the question as answered